# Typescript error with Zod and Prisma Schema

Tags: typescript, prisma, fastify

This is my first ever TypeScript project and I am using Fastify and Prisma to build it. I have extensively searched for this error and it's not a generic one. Similar questions were not helpful to my case. I am working on a User table where I have the prisma.schema as:

```
model User {
  id          Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String
  lastName    String
  email       String            @unique
  phone       String            @unique
  room        Room?             @relation(fields: [roomId], references: [id])
  roomId      Int?
  utilities   Utility[]
  rentStatus  Boolean?
  amountDue   Float?      
  dateSigned  DateTime?
  dateLeft    DateTime?
  createdAt   DateTime          @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime          @updatedAt
}
```

I have a user.schema.ts that contains the Zod schema for validation:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const createUserSchema = z.object({
    firstName: z.string({
        required_error: "First name is required"
    }),
    lastName: z.string({
        required_error: "Last name is required"
    }),
    email: z.string({
        required_error: "Email is required",
        invalid_type_error: "Email must be a string"
    }).email(),
    phone: z.string({
        required_error: "Phone number is required"
    })
});

export type CreateUserInput = z.infer<typeof createUserSchema>
```

In my user.service.ts I have this setup:

```
import prisma from "../utils/prisma";
import { CreateUserInput } from "./user.schema";

export async function createUser(input: CreateUserInput) {
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
        data: input
    });
}
```

But "data" is errored out with this:

```
(property) data: (Prisma.Without<Prisma.UserCreateInput, Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateInput> & Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Prisma.Without<Prisma.UserUncheckedCreateInput, Prisma.UserCreateInput> & Prisma.UserCreateInput)
The data needed to create a User.

Type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; email?: string; phone?: string; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<UserCreateInput, UserUncheckedCreateInput> & UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UserCreateInput)'.
  Type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; email?: string; phone?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Without<UserUncheckedCreateInput, UserCreateInput> & UserCreateInput'.
    Type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; email?: string; phone?: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UserCreateInput'.
      Property 'firstName' is optional in type '{ firstName?: string; lastName?: string; email?: string; phone?: string; }' but required in type 'UserCreateInput'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1911, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type '{ select?: UserSelect; include?: UserInclude; data: (Without<UserCreateInput,UserUncheckedCreateInput> & UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UserCreateInput); }'
```

Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of this error. One thing that stands out though is it complaining about firstName, lastName, email and phone being optional. But I have set it as required both in Zod and Prisma. It seems like I am missing something very trivial here.

Comment: I would recommend you to use zod-prisma to circumvent this issue instead of native zod: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod-prisma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Shea I was able to narrow down the issue. Looks like Zod was creating optional fields for firstName, lastName, email and phone, even though I did not have them set to optional. The fix was adding `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json` under `"compilerOptions"`.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your `user.schema` file is, it is emitting a type `CreateUserInput` which lists all the properties of a `User` as optional. That is incompatible with Prisma's expected type for `await prisma.user.create` which expects some fields which are required. Because you are passing in `input` which has type `CreateUserInput`, Prisma thinks all those fields are optional. Your error lies in why `CreateUserInput` has its fields listed as optional, which seems to be something to do with `z.infer`

Comment: That's all of the user.schema file above, where I have not set anything optional. My question is why does Prisma think that the fields are optional? Can you shed some more light on what may be wrong with z.infer?

Comment: I imagine there's an issue with how `z.infer` is reading your Zod schema - if you hover over `CreateUserInput` in the file where you declare the `User` schema, it should tell you what the TypeScript type is. Your problem has something to do with Zod, not with Prisma, as far as I can tell. I don't have a lot of experience with Zod, but I'll keep trying to look into it

Comment: Hey, Thanks to you I looked more into Zod and like you thought Zod was the culprit, apparently, it adds optional fields. So adding `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json`